# Lazy loading of images in angular7

Tags: html, angular, lazy-loading

I am getting 5000 images from the backend. I images need to be lazy-loaded and I have watched some videos and implemented ng-lazyload-image module but it's not working as expected and My page is getting crash every time after few seconds and also that tab lagging very much.I supposed to do [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbfWo.png)

i tried doing this

```js
  albums:any[];
  photos:any[];
  defaultImage = 'https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000';
  offset = 50;

  constructor(private service: AlbumService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list()
    this.pics()
  }
  list() {
    this.service.getAlbums().subscribe(res => {
      this.albums = res;
      console.log(this.albums)
    });
  }

  pics() {
    this.service.getPhotos().subscribe(res => {
      this.photos = res;
      console.log(this.photos)
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let album of albums">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{album.title}}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">id:{{album.id}},userid:{{album.userId}}</h6>
      <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding" *ngFor="let photo of photos">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <img [lazyLoad]="photo['url']" [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [offset]="offset">

          </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: 5000 images! i think you also need to look in to virtual scrolling

Comment: Virtual Scrolling is definitely the way to go! Basically it will dynamically render objects as needed depending on your scroll position. I used it for a searchable select box with around 1000 elements and it really made a difference!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kanulq) StackBlitz of your code...seems to be working.

Comment: Viqas its not working. don't know why

Answer (score 3):

You should use Virtual scrolling or Infinte scrolling.

- Virtual scrolling is better for performance beacause the number of
  records is fixed, we recycle DOM elements to display new data as they
  scroll off the screen.
- Infinite scroll you fetch a set number of records and insert them
  into a list, once you reach the bottom it'll fetch the next batch and
  insert them into the list and repeat that as long as you have items
  to fetch.

this is an example of [virtual scrolling](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll?file=app%2Fvirtual-scroll%2Fvirtual-scroll.component.html)